# How to setup WiFi network to access internet

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, broadband

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux. After some efforts I got the Internet working with `pppoeconf`.

Now I have desktop setup with Ubuntu + D-Link DSL 2730U ADSL modem router + brodband internet(BSNL india) connection. I would like to share and use this connection with mobile/laptop as well. Could someone please guild me how can I do this under Ubuntu.

I checked some other threads and checked `lspci|grep -i wireless` command output. So this does not get any output on my terminal.

Answer (score -1):

check below link it will help you

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc